# Visit system - 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Creating a system where if i press a button i can visit a place and then un-visit if i have pressed the wrong button. this will upload to the database and delete from the database depending on whether the button has been clicked. At the moment though i am getting the error:

```
'Trying to get property of non-object' and the place_id seems to be the problem as its being shown as null.
```

Tables: places: id, etc

Visit: id, place_id, user_id, timestamps

Controller: `

```
      $place_id = $request['placeId']; 
      $place = Place::find($place_id); 
      $visited = Auth::user()->visitors()->where('place_id', $place_id)->first(); 

      if($visited == null) {
        $visited = new Visit(); 
        $visited->user_id = Auth::user(); 
        $visited->place_id = $place->id; 
        $visited->save(); 
return null; 
} else{`

         $visited->delete();
         return null;
         }
```

AJAX:

```
    var placeId = 0;
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var urlVisit = '{{ route('visitss') }}';
    $('.visit').on('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     placeId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['place_id'];

$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlVisit,
             data: { place_id: placeId, _token: token}
     })
        .done(function() {

        });

        });
```

Any ideas on how to fix this and get the place_id to recognise the place that is being visited?

Comment: is this error happening when attempting to write to the database? Read from the database, or reading from the webpage when the button is clicked?

Comment: seems to be in the controller. the issues seems to be on the $place_id being null

Comment: Only try to add new Visit if `$place_id != 0` or `$place_id > 0`

Comment: How will that fix if the place_id is coming back null. The problem is the fact the place_id is coming back null when the visit button is placed on the place.blade, i need the $place_id not to be null

Comment: Should 'placetId' have the 't' in, or should it be 'placeId'   

`$place_id = $request['placetId'];`

Comment: Apologies that was a typo, the issues still remain. place_id is null

Comment: Then you have something wrong in your view. We don't know, how you are populating this field. Please post your view then... There is also a typo in your example {} else{`} btw...

Comment: where is the typo? bart also what should be in my button at the moment it is just. <a class="like">Visit?</a> should this be where place_id is defined?

Comment: @detinu20 the typo is after else{ declaration in your Controller, but I believe it is not relevant and happened via copy/pasting....

Comment: @detinu20 I want to help. Your button without rest of the code is doing nothing meaningful, so please post your full view with javascript declaration also.

Comment: just posted another answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170820/discussion-between-bart-and-detinu20).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="place-name">
                <a class="btn btn-not-visited visit" >Visited?</a>
<h1>$place->name</h1>
<p>$place->address</p>
</div>
```

The JS

```
 var placeId = 0;
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var urlVisit = '{{ route('visitss') }}';
    $('.visit').on('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     placeId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['place_id'];

$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlVisit,
             data: { place_id: placeId, _token: token}
     })
        .done(function() {

        });

        });
```

I presume im missing a 'place_id, $place->id' somewhere in the button?

Comment: Your `placeId` gets null right? So there is a problem with this line `placeId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['place_id'];` Where are you trying to get this value from? If you are unsure how to traverse DOM use `console.log(placeId);` after setting this value...

Comment: Comes back undefined if i use console log

Comment: this is expected behavior, with your current code. My idea was, that you would try different options, to find DOM node, that returns your wanted `place_id`. Please post your source file, with exact location of your `place` definition, from where `place_id` should be taken and populated to your js `placeId` var...